# Spark REST API Post Request does not return a response

Tags: python, rest, api, apache-spark

I am trying to launch a pyspark job using SPARK REST API. I put in the post request but I do not get any response.

My environment is the following:

- Linux Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS Bionic
- Java Version 1.8.0_211-b12 SE Runtime Environment
- Spark version 2.4.3
- Python version 3.7.1
- Scala version 2.11.12

Here's my attempt:

1. I started the master and slave nodes:
   `./sbin/start-all.sh`
   [image]
2. I see the following user interface on my browser:
   [image]
3. I enter the following command in terminal:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.43.88:34481/v1/submissions/create \
     --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
     --data '{"action":"CreateSubmissionRequest",\
              "appArgs":["/home/daniel/Documents/pyfiles/spark_pi.py"],\
              "appResource":"file:/home/daniel/Documents/pyfiles/spark_pi.py",\
              "clientSparkVersion":"2.4.3",\
              "environmentVariables":{"SPARK_ENV_LOADED":"1"},\
              "mainClass":"org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit",\
              "sparkProperties":{"spark.driver.supervise":"false",\
              "spark.app.name":"Simple App",\
              "spark.eventLog.enabled":"true",\
              "spark.submit.deployMode":"cluster",\
              "spark.master":"spark://daniel-K501UX:7077"}}'
```

[image]

I don't get a response even after waiting for 10+ minutes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did u solve @Daniel Lee

Comment: No. I did not find a solution. :(